# Simple AND secure command line HTTP server

Tags: command-line, file-server

A follow-up question to this one from 2012: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32182/simple-command-line-http-server

Does anyone know a simple file webserver that is also secure? Many propose using http.server from Python, but [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) explicitly state

> Warning http.server is not recommended for production. It only
> implements basic security checks.

Basic Requirements:

- should (only) be able to serve a directory
- the focus should be on exposing the socket to the Internet without the worry of a take-over or similar events
- docs should at least have a positive security note (in contrast to what Python stdlib says about its http.server)

Comment: related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/226095/pythons-http-server-library-basic-security-checks

Comment: Please be more specific about "serve a directory". Links? Authentication? Cookies?

Comment: @waltinator You might need to inform yourself what "serving static files" in the context of HTTP servers means. The following docs can be helpful: Apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html & NGINX: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/ - Links/Authentication/Cookies don't play role (as in the question from 2012).

Comment: WSGI module for a simple file webserver is overkill, I suppose. Right now, I fix the situation using an nginx (but apache would work as well sure). I bothers me that people do not read the security note. :-/ I will think about security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Can you move the question over to security.stackexchange.com or should I copy/paste it there in its current form?

Comment: @SvenR.Kunze It is off-topic on the security SE. It should be moved to the softwarerecs SE. I can not move it, but we both can suggest the mods to do that (click "flag" below the question, then "needs moderator intervention", then ask politely). I do the same, if they get 2 suggestions that increases the probability that they will move it.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica You are right. I don't see why I thought about security SE.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/)

> Radically simplified static file serving for Python web apps
>
> With a couple of lines of config WhiteNoise allows your web app to
> serve its own static files, making it a self-contained unit that can
> be deployed anywhere without relying on nginx, Amazon S3 or any other
> external service. (Especially useful on Heroku, OpenShift and other
> PaaS providers.)
>
> It’s designed to work nicely with a CDN for high-traffic sites so you
> don’t have to sacrifice performance to benefit from simplicity.
>
> WhiteNoise works with any WSGI-compatible app but has some special
> auto-configuration features for Django.
>
> WhiteNoise takes care of best-practices for you, for instance:
>
> Serving compressed content (gzip and Brotli formats, handling
> Accept-Encoding and Vary headers correctly)
>
> Setting far-future cache headers on content which won’t change
>
> Worried that serving static files with Python is horribly inefficient?
> Still think you should be using Amazon S3? Have a look at the
> Infrequently Asked Questions below.

I use it in my Django projects.